# My app on Android Studio doesn't compile with JVM 1.8

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. You can try some of the following options:

- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
  Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.  Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. You can try some of the following options:
- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

Comment: So use Java 11 - what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded your project to use Gradle 7 you need to use Java 11. If you dont want to use Java 11 for whatever reason you need to downgrade your gradle version for your project

Comment: How can I change?

Comment: in your projects `build.gradle` change the version to what you had before. 4.2.2 I believe was the last version

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by changing the configuration in the IDE:

1. Go to the setting
2. Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
3. Change Gradle JDK

[image]

Comment: While it's not super clear, Java 8 and Java 11 are the only production releases (LTS or long term support) of Java right now.  All other releases are interim releases to test and demonstrate new features.  In September of 2021, Java 17, the next LTS version, will be released.  What that means is that the Java 14 you chose was no longer supported as of September of 2020.  See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix it for IDE and command line (useful for CI) set this in `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/your/jdk11
```